# Lib.Harmony resharper Name '__instance' does not match rule 'Parameters'. Suggested name is 'instance'

Tags: c#, resharper, rider, suppress-warnings, harmony

Any ideas on how I can not just suppress/ignore but instead say to resharper that this is expected and okay for me? I'm using JetBrains Rider 2023

Adding the attribute of inconsistent naming [SupressWarning] is not what I need

[image: example of the warnings]

Comment: If suppressing the warning is not what you need, what do you need instead?

Comment: Instead, I thought about suppressing this warning on a global level because Harmony is used in many places in my project and I could have an inconsistent naming but it suppressed by the attribute

Comment: You can downgrade this warning via the `DotSettings` file to whatever you want (e. g. _Suggestion_)